# ¿Cómo compilo un archivo .cpp en Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

mi problema es que no sé si haya la posibilidad de compilar un archivo .cpp desde Visual Studio, ya que cuando abro algún archivo con dicha extensión, no sé como probar si funciona. Traté creando un proyecto con c++ y ahí si me da la opción para correr el programa, pero si abro solo el archivo, ya no me deja.
Esto es lo que me sale:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Estás confundiendo compilar un solo archivo con ejecutar el código de un solo archivo.

Si lo que realmente quieres es ejecutar un solo archivo, no podrás hacerlo a no ser que éste tenga un [punto de entrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_de_entrada_(inform%C3%A1tica)), y no podrás ejecutarlo en Visual Studio a no ser que forme parte de un proyecto.

Si lo que en realidad necesitas es compilar un solo archivo, puedes hacerlo abriendo el archivo en el proyecto y pulsar <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, o si no quieres crear un proyecto usa la línea de comandos:

> ```
> cl archivo.cpp
> ```

Answer (score 1):

No es posible compilar un archivo individual con VisualStudio.

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un proyecto (tendrás que elegir si vas a crear un ejecutable o una librería). Después añades el fichero al proyecto y entonces ya sí podrás compilarlo.

Esto es así porque las opciones de compilación que ofrece VisualStudio son inmensas y la única forma de gestionarlas es configurando un proyecto.